# Has anyone been able to edit text in an OpenWYSIWYG control dynamically?

Tags: javascript, openwysiwyg

Like the question says has anyone been able to take a [OpenWYSIWYG](http://www.openwebware.com/) control and change its contents dynamically with JavaScript?  It's hard because it takes your textarea and transforms it into a WYSIWYG editor by making the textarea invisible and inserting some kind of iframe and uses that as the editor.

I've tried code like this but failed:

```
document.getElementById("textarea-wysiwyg").value = "BLARG";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that is it the only frame on the page then you can do something like this:

```
window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML = 'blarg'
```

The above works when I tried it on http://www.openwebware.com/wysiwyg/demo.shtml in firebug.

Hope this helps...